# Automatically add and remove items from Tablist

Tags: java, bukkit

Hey guys I was just making my tablist plugin. I've been trying this for a little bit. I've tried multiple things and none have come out working so far. My goal is to automatically add a faction members name if they join to the tablist showing the members online and automatically remove it.

Clearer explanation:
The faction members name has to be displayed on the tablist when they join. I tried doing it and it just grouped them all together in 1 entry or 1 slot on the tablist.
I want them to be displayed 1 name in 1 tabslot.

how could I do this any ideas?

Anyone got any ideas? Here is my code (this doesn't include the automatic join and leave)

Code is pretty much useless but here it is

```
 if (fplayer.hasFaction())
{
  list.setSlot(0, "", ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "Home:", "");
  if (faction.hasHome())
  {
    int x = faction.getHome().getBlockX();
    int z = faction.getHome().getBlockZ();

    String xz = x + ", " + z;

    list.setSlot(3, "", ChatColor.BLUE.toString(), ChatColor.YELLOW + xz);
  }
  else
  {
    list.setSlot(3, "", ChatColor.DARK_RED.toString(), ChatColor.YELLOW + "Not Set");
  }
  list.setSlot(1, "", ChatColor.translateAlternateColorCodes('&', plugin.getConfig().getString("SERVER-NAME")), "");

  list.setSlot(2, "", ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "End Portals:", "");
  list.setSlot(5, "", ChatColor.YELLOW + plugin.getConfig().getString("END-PORTAL-COORDS"), "");
  list.setSlot(8, "", ChatColor.YELLOW + "in each ", ChatColor.YELLOW + "quadrant.");


  int KILLS = Stats.kdc.getInt("p." + p.getUniqueId().toString() + ".kills");
  String KILLSS = Integer.toString(KILLS);
  int DEATHS = Stats.kdc.getInt("p." + p.getUniqueId().toString() + ".deaths");
  String DEATHSS = Integer.toString(DEATHS);

  list.setSlot(22, "", ChatColor.DARK_BLUE.toString(), ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "Player Info:");
  list.setSlot(25, "", ChatColor.YELLOW + "Kills: ", ChatColor.YELLOW + KILLSS);
  list.setSlot(28, "", ChatColor.YELLOW + "Deaths: ", ChatColor.YELLOW + DEATHSS);

  DecimalFormat dtrf = new DecimalFormat("#.###");

  list.setSlot(10, "", ChatColor.DARK_GREEN.toString(), ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "Faction Info:");
  list.setSlot(13, "", ChatColor.YELLOW + "DTR: ", String.valueOf(dtrf.format(faction.getDTR())));
  list.setSlot(16, "", ChatColor.YELLOW + "Online: ", String.valueOf(faction.getOnlinePlayers().size() + "/" + faction.getSize()));

  int x = p.getLocation().getBlockX();
  int z = p.getLocation().getBlockZ();

  String xz = "(" + x + ", " + z + ")";

  list.setSlot(34, "", ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "Location:", "");

  list.setSlot(37, "", ChatColor.UNDERLINE.toString(), ChatColor.YELLOW + "Unknown");

  list.setSlot(40, ChatColor.GRAY + "[" + getCardinalDirection(p) + "] ", ChatColor.MAGIC.toString(), ChatColor.GRAY + xz);

  list.setSlot(46, "", ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "KoTH:", "");
  list.setSlot(49, "", ChatColor.YELLOW + "Name: ", ChatColor.YELLOW + "None");
  list.setSlot(52, "", ChatColor.YELLOW + "Loc: ", ChatColor.YELLOW + "None");
  list.setSlot(55, "", ChatColor.YELLOW + "Time: ", ChatColor.YELLOW + "None");

  list.setSlot(15, "", ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "Kit:", "");
  list.setSlot(18, "", ChatColor.YELLOW + plugin.getConfig().getString("MAP-KIT"), "");

  list.setSlot(24, "", ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "Border:", "");
  list.setSlot(27, "", ChatColor.YELLOW + plugin.getConfig().getString("BORDER-COORDS"), "");

  int i = 0;
  for (Player o : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
    i++;
  }
  list.setSlot(33, "", ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + "Players Online ", ChatColor.DARK_PURPLE + ": ");
  list.setSlot(36, "", ChatColor.WHITE.toString(), ChatColor.YELLOW + String.valueOf(i));

  list.setDefaultPing(1);
```

Comment: Perhaps you should look here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html

Comment: Look at  Tedstar, Dec 28, 2015 answer #16. https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/add-fake-players-to-tablist.111142/

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 My tablist works fine. The issue im facing is adding and removing players that are in the other players faction by automatically creating a custom slot

Answer (score 0):

You can hook onto Factions and listen for the event that's fired when a player joins/leaves a faction, then loop through the players of the source and target factions, updating their tablists on the way.

*Or you could do it the more laggy way, by setting up an **ASYC** repeating task that attempts to update all player's tablists regardless of their faction status. The reason I say **ASYC** is because if the method fails, you won't cause an interrupt on the main server thread.*